# Radar signals features for machine learning

Tags: signal-analysis

I have project in which I have to classify materials based on the spectra of received  radar signal. I want to create feature vectors of the specific materials. Can anyone share his ideas. ?

Comment: How about you share your ideas / concerns ?

Comment: Adding on to the previous comment: what have you done this far? What band is your radar operating at? What is the system bandwidth? What materials are you hoping to differentiate?

Comment: Hello Thank you so much for your prompt reply. Actually I now in literature review so haven't started practically  but basically I will be using 77 Ghz (automotive) FMCW radar. My goal is to classify material ( metal , glass, wood etc) based on the received signal spectrogram. But operating at this band the point cloud  is not  so dense as compared to Lidar and camera. I have to implement paper " https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328523480_One-Shot_Learning_for_Robust_Material_Classification_Using_Millimeter-Wave_Radar_System.

Comment: But for research purposes I have to increase distance between radar and object. In this particular example they have used CAPON beaming algorithm but instead I will use heatmaps by mmw Gui provided by texas instruments. so my questions is what features other than range, angle can be used. Sorry if my questions has confused you.  I can explain more if needed,